# Permission Denied installing boring_generators in ruby on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to install boring_generators gem in my ruby on rails 6 project in windows 10 os. But I couldn't install it, I got errors like below. I would be grateful if anyone gives me the idea to fix it.
gem install boring_generators

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink - (../acorn/bin/acorn, C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/boring_generators-0.11.0/tmp/templates/app_template/node_modules/.bin/acorn)

Comment: Do append the `sudo` keyword in the command as like `sudo gem install boring_generators`

Comment: actually, i'm trying to do it in windows 10